# Formik Field Depending on Two Others

Tags: reactjs, formik, use-effect, formik-material-ui

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-jackson-rq6il) that shows 3 formik fields: first name, last name, and name.

I'm trying to make the field `name` display `${firstName} ${lastName}` only until the user modifies the `name` field themselves, and so the condition `name === firstName + ' ' + lastName` fails, after which the `name` field should not be automatically updated anymore.

The challenge is that I'm trying to make this code live in the `MyContactForm.tsx` file since I need to be reusing that logic of inter-field dependency in other similar `My*Form.tsx` components thereafter, and therefore reuse the "generic" `MyForm.tsx` component without change.

Comment: I think most people do not understand what it is you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to disable the name field after the first change? There are default values already in the sandbox. I think I can help if I understood exactly what you're trying to achieve. Also to note the condition you mention is not in sandbox code making it harder to understand the goal.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I'm trying to stop making the name field follow the changes of first and last name fields, only when the user updates the name field themselves to make it equal to something other than first name + space + last name. Is that clearer?

Comment: The way it works right now is that the `name` is updated only if `Display Name` is directly modified. There's no such a thing as `firstName + ' ' + lastName`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant givenName and familyName, not firstName and lastName. Yes, what I would like to happen is that if `name = givenName + ' ' + familyName` and the user modifies `givenName` or `familyName` then `name` should change accordingly. Otherwise, if the user "breaks the link" by modifying `name` manually, then it should stop updating.

Comment: did the answer solve your problem? or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Sammy , please update the usage of `familyName` by `lastName` and `givenName` by `firstName` in the question because devs. get really mad at the wrong explanation. You may get a downvote on this question even though your question/requirement is a fair one.

Comment: @Jackson, no, I'm sorry, I don't see how this satisfies the fact that I need the dependency logic to be reusable.

Comment: I guess that was an error, I’m sorry :-(

Comment: Actually i was planning to use yup validation to transform the response.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224902/discussion-between-ypahalajani-and-sammy).

Comment: I see... yes, this might indeed be an approach @ypahalajani

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Will post a solution here is a few hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a couple of changes so that your usage of `MyContactForm` is unchanged.

1. Added an optional prop `onChange: (nextValue: string) => void` to `MyTextField` so that this will be called when the field value is changed
2. Added our custom logic in the above-defined callback so that the previous form logic is extended not over-ridden.
3. Added a `follow` field in the form inside the `MyCustomForm` to decide whether to track the changes from `firstName` and `lastName` or not. (Check the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224902/discussion-between-ypahalajani-and-sammy) for the pseudo code)
4. Destructed the `follow` prop when calling the form submission callback from `App.tsx` such the developer only receives only those form values that he/she is expecting/seeing from `MyContactForm`

[image]

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-field-depending-on-two-others-stackoverflow-jp2qt?file=/src/App.tsx) is the forked sandbox which contains the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment I've made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wiles-tp9xl) which links the `display name` to `name` and `last name` as long as user doesn't modify the `display name` manually. As far as making this logic generic, I'd argue against that unless you have hundreds of forms with various fields in which case you'd need to generate a single form dynamically and that goes in a very different conversation.

Comment: Why is there a lag in your solution? I mean - when you type something in the `lastName` field it does not reflects immediately on the first go.
After you keep typing in characters in the same input box, then the change is seen/reflected (in the `Display Name` box) and that too the result lags by one character input - like if I have added `sss` in lastName/familyName, the `Display Name` reflects - `${firstName} ${lastName}ss`.

Are you sure your solution is working correctly?

Comment: Check this gif for the behaviour: https://ibb.co/GkNWVWb